# Extract element from HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have html:

```
<div class="img-holder">
 <h1>Sample Image</h1>
 <img src="http://sample.com/img.jpg"/>
</div>
```

With:

```
s = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'img-holder'}).h1
s = s.get_text()
```

Displays the 'Sample image'.

How do i get the image src using the same format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `img.attrs["src"]`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div class="img-holder">
 <h1>Sample Image</h1>
 <img src="http://sample.com/img.jpg"/>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
s = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'img-holder'})
print( s.img.attrs["src"] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
soup.find('img')['src']
```

Comment: I was trying this initially, but when you need specific img inside specific <div> this doesn't help.